# Wordpress, related Posts how to add ALT tag to img?

Tags: php, wordpress

So, I do have a function to get related posts in my functions.php for Wordpress. It is working fine BUT the images do not have an alt tag.

Part of my code:

```
 $img = genesis_get_image() ? genesis_get_image( array( 'size' => 'related' ) ) : '<img src="' . get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/images/related.png" alt="' . get_the_title() . '" />';

                $related .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" rel="bookmark" title="' . get_the_title() . '">' . $img . '<p>' . get_the_title() . '</p></a></li>';
```

Any idea how I can tell Wordpress to add the title as alt tag, like it is with the title tag inside the link?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution. Don`t know if it`s a special thing because of the Genesis Framework I`m using or if this is a general Wordpress.

However with adding attr to the genesis_get_image array it was done.

```
'attr' => array ('alt' => 'Related Image')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the POST|PAGE ID as a get_the_title() parameter.

Inside the loop, single.php or page.php:

```
get_the_title( get_the_ID() );
```

Outside the loop: You need to get the post ID before.

```
$post_id = X (there are many ways to get the ID);
get_the_title( $post_id );
```

To help you how to get the post ID, I want to know more about your file.

What file is? Single, Page, Category (inside loop)...